# SQL delete trigger in

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Assuming I have three tables:

**Table_1:**

```
 ID     INT     PRIMARY
 name NVARCHAR
```

**Table_2:**

```
ID         INT    PRIMARY
Table_1_ID INT (foreign key)
```

**Table_3:**

```
ID         INT    PRIMARY
Table_2_ID INT (foreign key)
```

The first two tables have the following triggers:

```
-- Table_1
CREATE TRIGGER tr_1
ON Table_1
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Table_2
    WHERE Table_1_ID IN (SELECT deleted.ID FROM Table_1)

    DELETE FROM Table_1
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)
END

-- Table_2
CREATE TRIGGER sr_bf_trigger_delete_ID
ON Table_2
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Table_3
    WHERE Table_2_ID IN (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)

    DELETE FROM Table_2
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)
END
```

The idea is, that once I delete a row (or rows) in `Table_1`, it will start the trigger and delete the corresponding rows in `Table_2`. However, before deleting the rows in `Table_2`, corresponding rows in `Table_3` are deleted.

Would this work? The possible problem I see is that both times I access the same "deleted"-Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your triggers will work fine with minor corrections (removed typos):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_1
ON Table_1
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Table_2
    WHERE Table_1_ID IN (SELECT d.ID FROM deleted as d)

    DELETE FROM Table_1
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT d.ID FROM deleted as d)
END;

-- Table_2
CREATE TRIGGER sr_bf_trigger_delete_ID
ON Table_2
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Table_3
    WHERE Table_2_ID IN (SELECT d.ID FROM deleted as d)

    DELETE FROM Table_2
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT d.ID FROM deleted as d)
END;
```

See <kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5821c/1)</kbd>